# Android Firebase: Error while generating a release certificate fingerprint

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-oauth, google-developers-console

im trying to generate a release certificate fingerprint for a google sign in with firebase and this is my problem
this is my command:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
  -alias goworkkey -keystore /home/ryan/Desktop/keystore.jks
```

This is my result:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: 
Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.
```

if i try this:

```
sudo keytool -list -v -keystore /home/ryan/Desktop/keystore.jks -alias googlekey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I get this:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1807)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:1687)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:908)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while running the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v -storepass android
```

If I changed it to this:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

I was properly asked for a password, as explained here, https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth 
and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the problem? As this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_9tk7ME4ZU) go to the "**Gradle projects**" tab (to the right) -> **Tasks** -> **android** -> double click on **signingReport** and you will get it for all your variants: Take the SHA1 which have the Variant and Config type debug

I hope it will be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on **Project Structure** which is on the right of Android Studio.
2. Click on **Ads**.
3. Tick **AdMob**
4. Click **OK** button
5. Wait for sync or manually sync if necessary.